# How to parse, and render, json for use in Flask template

Tags: python, json, templates, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to learn the ins and outs of Flask. But I'm confused about how I can render data pulled from Twitter's API in a template.

Here's my Flask app code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

auth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=1'

response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)

# create the app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def show_tweets():
    tweets = response
    return render_template('show_tweets.html', tweets = tweets)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And a snippet from the `show_tweets.html` template:

```
<ul>
{% for tweet in tweets %}
    <li>{{ tweet }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't load the JSON data from the Twitter response; use the [`Response.json()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) to load the data into a Python list:

```
tweets = response.json()
```

The result is a list of dictionaries, see the [`statuses/user_timeline` API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

In your template you can then loop over these dictionaries and pull out information:

```
<ul>
{% for tweet in tweets %}
    <li>{{ tweet.text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

would show the `text` key for each tweet, for example. See the [Tweets API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets) as to what keys are present, and what type of information each key provides.